# Error when trying to Copy Excel Range and PasteSpecial in PowerPoint Slide (using Late Binding)

Tags: vba, excel, powerpoint

I am using Late Binding to Copy `Charts` and `Range` from Excel to PowerPoint.

I am getting the following error:

[image]

At the this line of code:

```
Set myShape = ppSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile, msoFalse)
```

**Note**: I am using the `Range.Copy` and `Shapes.PasteSpecial` as `ppPasteEnhancedMetafile` since after a lot of trial and error it gives the best resolution in PowerPoint.

**Note #2**: Using this `PasteSpecial` as `ppPasteEnhancedMetafile` worked fine for me when I was using **Early Binding**. I had to switch to Late Binding due to the fact that we have users running Office 2010, Office 2013 and Office 2016 (and I don't want them playing with the VB Project Ref. to the PowerPoint Library).

**My Code**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub UpdatePowerPoint(PowerPointFile)

Dim ppProgram                           As Object
Dim ppPres                              As Object
Dim CurOpenPresentation                 As Object
Dim ppSlide                             As Object    
Dim myShape                             As Object
Dim SlideNum                            As Integer
Dim StageStat                           As String

On Error Resume Next
Set ppProgram = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
On Error GoTo 0

If ppProgram Is Nothing Then
    Set ppProgram = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
Else
    If ppProgram.Presentations.Count > 0 Then
        For Each CurOpenPresentation In ppProgram.Presentations ' loop through all open presnetations (check Full Name: Path and name)

            Dim CleanFullName As String * 1024
            CleanFullName = Replace(CurOpenPresentation.FullName, "%20", " ")  ' replace Sharepoint characters %20 with Space (" ")

            Dim comStr  As String * 1024
            comStr = CStr(PowerPointFile)

            If StrComp(comStr, CleanFullName, vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
                 Set ppPres = CurOpenPresentation
                 Exit For
            End If
        Next CurOpenPresentation
    End If
End If

If ppPres Is Nothing Then ' if One-Pager presentation was not found from all open presentations
    Set ppPres = ppProgram.Presentations.Open(PowerPointFile, msoFalse)
End If

ppProgram.Visible = True    
SlideNum = 1

Set ppSlide = ppPres.Slides(SlideNum) ' set the slide

' --- loop throughout the Slide shapes and search for the Shape of type chart , then delete the old ones
For i = ppSlide.Shapes.Count To 1 Step -1
    If ppSlide.Shapes.Item(i).HasChart Or ppSlide.Shapes.Item(i).Type = msoEmbeddedOLEObject Or ppSlide.Shapes.Item(i).Type = msoPicture Then
       ppSlide.Shapes.Item(i).Delete
    End If
Next i

' copy range from Excel Sheet
OnePgrSht.Range("A1:Q33").Copy

' ***** Error at the line below ***** 
Set myShape = ppSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(ppPasteEnhancedMetafile, msoFalse) ' Paste to PowerPoint    
' Set Pasted Picture object properties:
With myShape
    .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
    .Width = ExcelPicObj_Width
    .Height = ExcelPicObj_Height
    .Left = ExcelPicObj_Pos_Left
    .Top = ExcelPicObj_Pos_Top
    .ZOrder msoSendToBack
End With

ppPres.Save
OnePgrSht.Activate ' <-- restore mouse focus on "One-Pager" sheet

Set ppSlide = Nothing
Set ppPres = Nothing
Set ppProgram = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: To paste a Range, I generally use `ppPasteHTML`. Not sure if `ppPasteEnhancedMetafile` can be used for Ranges...

Comment: @R3uK are you sure ? I was able to `PasteSpecial` as `ppPasteEnhancedMetafile` when I was using **Early Binding** (before switching to **Late Binding**)

Comment: Dunno, I'm looking on the web at the moment, didn't find something pertinent yet. You could paste the range as `ppPasteEnhancedMetafile` in Early Binding? So I was probably wrong! Did you change anything else than the declaration as Object?

Comment: @R3uK I've made a "few" to support late binding, all work well, except for the part of the `PasteSpecial`. FYI, changing to `ppPasteHTML` resulted with the same error.

Comment: Only thing interesting is the description of the DataType parameter in the PasteSpecial method that says *A format for the Clipboard contents when they're inserted into the document. The default value varies, depending on the contents in the Clipboard.*  **An error occurs if the specified data type in the DataType argument is not supported by the clipboard contents.**

Comment: Ok, so the error isn't coming from there! I'll dig too! ;)

Comment: Is `OnePgrSht` a public variable? Because I don't see it before the `Copy`

Comment: @R3uK yes, it's defined as `Public OnePgrSht As Worksheet`

Comment: 2 silly suggestions : Try decomposing the paste/set into 2 Rows `ppSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial ppPasteEnhancedMetafile, msoFalse: Set myShape = ppSlide.Shapes(ppSlide.Shapes.Count)`. If there still is the error (which will probably be), try pasting the copied range somewhere on the same sheet `OnePgrSht.Range("A1:Q33").Copy: OnePgrSht.Range("S1").Paste`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ppPasteEnhancedMetafile](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff744731.aspx) is a `PowerPoint`constant which is not available using late binding. This is because late binding does not include the `PowerPoint` library in which this constant is defined.

So you have to use

```
Set myShape = ppSlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial(2, msoFalse)
```

where 2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile.

Comment: I missed it! But shouldn't this throw a compilation error with `Option Explicit`?

Comment: @Axel Richter  Thank :) that did it. One more question, what is the value  of `ppAlignCenter` ? I need to modify also `.TextFrame.TextRange.Paragraphs.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = ppAlignCenter `.

Comment: What I do in this cases is googling for the constant names and then mostly find the enumerations. For ex.: [PpParagraphAlignment Enumeration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb251051%28v=office.12%29.aspx) containing `ppAlignCenter` constant.

Comment: Thanks for the Bonus +1 , I tried to find it in Google, wasn't able to find the link you have

Comment: If you write the code with the reference set, you can simply query the enum values in the Immediate window. I also prefer to declare constants with the values you want rather than using literal values. It makes the code more legible.

Comment: You can also find the values for enums using the VBA IDE in PowerPoint itself.  Either press F2 and use the Object Browser or (sometimes simpler) open the Immediate window and type ? ppPasteEnhancedMetafile or whatever other constant you need a value for.

Comment: @AxelRichter : Sorry to insist, but I don't get why this wouldn't raise a `Variable not declared` as there is `Option Explicit`... Could you share some light on that?

Comment: @R3uK: Using `Option Explicit` the usage of `ppPasteEnhancedMetafile` will raise a `Variable not declared` error if `ppPasteEnhancedMetafile` is not defined somewhere. Maybe it was defined somewhere but not set to 2?

Comment: @AxelRichter : thx for the answer, that's what I thought. I check in one of my project with a lot references but closest thing I find was `wdPasteEnhancedMetafile = 9`, so a bit strange but maybe the OP has indeed declared `ppPasteEnhancedMetafile` somewhere!

Comment: @R3uK: Using `Option Explicit` should be recommended but is not the all healing power. Each f*ing Add-In can declare and set constants and even overwrite functions and methods. Many Add-Ins defines `Replace` functions and then this functions will be used instead of `VBA.Strings.Replace` if you only call `Replace`.

Comment: @AxelRichter : Thx for the info about the Add-In overwrites, I work without it so I never stumbled upon such an issue, but it is good to know! :)